# How to integrate key vault with Bot composer

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

I want to make an http request from bot composer but one thing to pass while making http request needs to be kept a secret. So I want to fetch that value from key vault. Can someone tell how to integrate bot composer with key vault.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you are using Azure to run the bot, so I'll answer with that in mind. Otherwise let me know and I can expand the answer.

Take the secret from the settings of the bot. It's just like how you access `turn.activity.text`, but using [settings scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-dialog/adaptive-dialog-prebuilt-memory-states?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#settings-scope) instead of the turn scope. So: `settings.apiSecret`.

## Local Env

Now in development, local environment, you can just put the secret in the settings file.

## In Azure

When you deploy to your azure app service, you can use [Key Vault References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#reference-syntax) in the Configuration blade. Remember you need to [give the app service Secret Get permission to that Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault).

This is the easiest way since you don't need to write code to query KeyVault via the API.

## From DevOps to Azure

There's a way to get the secret in the pipeline, but I believe this is not something you need in this scenario, you just want to set the variable in the App Service. So in the App Service Deployment task, under Application and Configuration settings -> App Settings: you can add the same thing you'd put in the Configuration blade in the azure portal.
So you can add to the textbox: `-apiSecret @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)` or click on the button with the elipsis on the right and enter it on the form

Comment: Thank you for the above info . Is there a way to integrate key vault  with azure devops pipeline.

Comment: Edited the answer to incorporate that

Comment: glad this helped you, @be3112Rahulgarg. Would you mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: Can you mark it as the correct answer then?

Comment: @MartínLaRosa, please take my upvote.
Just a precision, it is required to enable your app service as a managed-identity (to assign permissions on the vault)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote @Brice. That is correct, it is explained in the link on how to give permissions to the app to access the vault.